# getting tree conflicts when merging with Subclipse

Tags: svn, merge, subclipse, tree-conflict

I am using Eclipse 8.6 and Subclipse 1.6, and svn 1.6.x server. I created a branch, made some changes in both branch and trunk, and now I am trying to merge from trunk to this branch. All what I am getting is nothing but tree conflicts for every directory and every file under the root of the branch. I get that even with my test project where I did nothing but edited one file. The problem is that I don't understand what these tree conflicts mean, since I did not change anything. I have only changed one file for testing and I am supposed to get the file update during merge, but this simply gets ignored. 
All I see in the merge window is tree conflict icons for each directory and each file under the root. Also under Tree Conflics window it tells me "local add, incoming add upon merge" for each of the tree conflicts.

Comment: What kind of tree conflict are you running in?

Comment: The same thing is happening for us with the same version of MyEclipse and Subclipse. We actually had to go back and use MyEclipse 7.5 for merging purposes - if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it!

Comment: Reckon this should be marked as accepted

Answer (score 7):

Right click Project > Team > Show tree conflicts
then select conflicts as mark as resolved.
The commit should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

[Resolving Conflicts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html) is a good starter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you have added any autoformating or anything of that sort enabled ?

The below thread might help resolve your problem.

http://www.mail-archive.com/harmony-dev@incubator.apache.org/msg05535.html